# No /opt/ml/input/config/resourceconfig.json error when training with Sagemaker Python SDK locally on WSL

Tags: windows-subsystem-for-linux, amazon-sagemaker, docker-desktop

The goal is to be able to run do Sagemaker local development and train locally with Docker images provided by AWS.  I have been able to get this working on a Ubuntu 20.04 VM with code and Docker all running on same VM, but unable to get it working with a WSL Ubuntu 20.04 + Docker Desktop setup.

With the setup below, I have been able to create a simple Docker image that calls a Python script to read from and write data to both WSL directories and the Windows automounted directories to prove the WSL Ubuntu + Docker Desktop is working OK.

Any help is appreciated - been struggling to get this working!

**Environment**

- WSL - Ubuntu 20.04 (unable to use WSL 2 due to VPN and DNS issues)
- Docker Desktop 3.1.0
- Python 3.7 (pip install numpy pandas sagemaker sagemaker[local])

**Setup**

- Code based on [amazon-sagemaker-local-mode tensorflow training](https://github.com/aws-samples/amazon-sagemaker-local-mode/tree/main/tensorflow_script_mode_local_training_and_serving)
- Code executing on WSL with DOCKER_HOST=tcp://localhost:2375
- `/etc/wsl.conf`:

```
[automount]
enabled = true
root = /
options = "metadata,umask=22,fmask=11,case=off"
```

- Error occurs when running code on both Windows mount `/c` or on WSL `/home`

**Issue**

The following code is throwing the error when `fit()` is called.

```
    mnist_estimator = TensorFlow(entry_point='mnist_tf2.py',
                                 role=dummy_role,
                                 instance_count=1,
                                 instance_type='local',
                                 framework_version='2.2',
                                 source_dir='/home/a632940/dev/sagemaker-local',
                                 py_version='py37',
                                 session=local_session,
                                 distribution={'parameter_server': {'enabled': True}})

    mnist_estimator.fit({'train': training_dataset_path})
```

**Error**

```
Creating network "sagemaker-local" with the default driver
Creating 0j3k45995o-algo-1-prqxb ... done
Attaching to 0j3k45995o-algo-1-prqxb
0j3k45995o-algo-1-prqxb | Reporting training FAILURE
0j3k45995o-algo-1-prqxb | framework error: 
0j3k45995o-algo-1-prqxb | Traceback (most recent call last):
0j3k45995o-algo-1-prqxb |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sagemaker_training/trainer.py", line 66, in train
0j3k45995o-algo-1-prqxb |     env = environment.Environment()
0j3k45995o-algo-1-prqxb |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sagemaker_training/environment.py", line 498, in __init__
0j3k45995o-algo-1-prqxb |     resource_config = resource_config or read_resource_config()
0j3k45995o-algo-1-prqxb |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sagemaker_training/environment.py", line 239, in read_resource_config
0j3k45995o-algo-1-prqxb |     return _read_json(resource_config_file_dir)
0j3k45995o-algo-1-prqxb |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sagemaker_training/environment.py", line 191, in _read_json
0j3k45995o-algo-1-prqxb |     with open(path, "r") as f:
0j3k45995o-algo-1-prqxb | FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/opt/ml/input/config/resourceconfig.json'
0j3k45995o-algo-1-prqxb | 
0j3k45995o-algo-1-prqxb | [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/opt/ml/input/config/resourceconfig.json'
0j3k45995o-algo-1-prqxb exited with code 2
```

**Source Code**

```
import os

import boto3
import numpy as np
import sagemaker.session
from sagemaker.local import LocalSession
from sagemaker.tensorflow import TensorFlow

data_files_list = ('train_data.npy', 'train_labels.npy',
                   'eval_data.npy', 'eval_labels.npy')

def download_training_and_eval_data(aws_session):
    if os.path.isfile('./data/train_data.npy') and \
            os.path.isfile('./data/train_labels.npy') and \
            os.path.isfile('./data/eval_data.npy') and \
            os.path.isfile('./data/eval_labels.npy'):
        print('Training and evaluation datasets exist. Skipping Download')
    else:
        print('Downloading training and evaluation dataset')
        s3 = aws_session.resource('s3')
        for filename in data_files_list:
            s3.meta.client.download_file('sagemaker-sample-data-us-east-1', 'tensorflow/mnist/' + filename,
                                         './data/' + filename)


def do_inference_on_local_endpoint(predictor):
    print(f'\nStarting Inference on endpoint.')
    correct_predictions = 0

    train_data = np.load('./data/train_data.npy')
    train_labels = np.load('./data/train_labels.npy')

    predictions = predictor.predict(train_data[:50])
    for i in range(0, 50):
        prediction = np.argmax(predictions['predictions'][i])
        label = train_labels[i]
        print('prediction is {}, label is {}, matched: {}'.format(
            prediction, label, prediction == label))
        if prediction == label:
            correct_predictions = correct_predictions + 1

    print('Calculated Accuracy from predictions: {}'.format(
        correct_predictions / 50))


def main():

    # AWS Setup
    aws_session = boto3.session.Session(profile_name='default')

    download_training_and_eval_data(aws_session)

    local_session = sagemaker.LocalSession()
    local_session.config = {'local': {'local_code': True}}
    dummy_role = 'arn:aws:iam::999999999999:role/Dummy-SageMaker--Role'
    
    training_dataset_path = "file://./data/"

    print('Starting model training.')

    mnist_estimator = TensorFlow(entry_point='mnist_tf2.py',
                                 role=dummy_role,
                                 instance_count=1,
                                 instance_type='local',
                                 framework_version='2.2',
                                 source_dir='/home/a632940/dev/sagemaker-local',
                                 py_version='py37',
                                 session=local_session,
                                 distribution={'parameter_server': {'enabled': True}})

    mnist_estimator.fit({'train': training_dataset_path})
    print('Completed model training')

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```